# Regex comma separated sub string within a string

Tags: regex

I need to get key value pair from string using regex.

String is something like

```
country=xxx,state=yyy,city=zzz,
```

then this regex

```
([^,=]+?)(=)([^,=]+?),
```

gives me 3 different key value pairs but if I have multiple comma separated values then only first is selected.

For e.g.

```
country=xxx,state=yyy,city=zzz,pqr,
```

then for city `pqr` is dropped. I want to have both `zzz,pqr` for the city.

Comment: If there should be a comma at the end try `([^,=\n]+?)(=)([^,=\n]+(?:,[^,=\n]+)*),` https://regex101.com/r/srQPam/1

Comment: `(\w+)=(.*?)(?=,(?:\w+=|$))` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/deGdwN/1).

Comment: Maybe this `(?:[^,=]+?)=(([^\n](?!=))+),`.

Comment: Are you committed to that input format? It's pretty horrible -- comma separates pairs, except when it separates values. Yuk!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well then you can't put a comma in those *to-be-avoided* chars, can you?

```
([^,=]+)(=)([^=]+),
```

Comment: `([^,=]+)=([^=]+),` if you don't want to capture that `=`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow consecutive comma's `,,` you might repeat matching a comma followed by any char except a `,` or `=`

You could ddd `\r\n` to the character class if you don't want to cross newlines.

```
([^,=]+)=([^,=]+(?:,[^,=]+)*),
```

- `([^,=]+)` Capture b, match any char except `,` or `=`
- `=` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^,=]+` Match 1+ times any char except `,` or `=`
  - `(?:,[^,=]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching the `,` followed by any char except `,` or `=`
- `)`, Close group 2 and match trailing  `,`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tIq9Ha/1)

**Note** that you can omit the `?` after `[^,=]+?` to make it non greedy as the negated character class can not match the following `=` in `([^,=]+?)(=)`